# Re-Writing jQuery Function to Work with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I wrote this small piece of jQuery that worked great in a Rails app:

```
$(".myfilter li").click(function () {
    $("." + $(this).data('class')).toggle('slow')
    $(this).toggleClass("secondary")
});
```

I'm trying to re-write the functionality using Meteor JS. Here is what I'm trying, however, it is not working:

```
Template.postList.events({
  "click .myfilter li":function(event, template) {
    template.$("." + $(this).data('class')).toggle('slow');
    template.$(this).toggleClass("secondary");
  }
});
```

Here are the HTML files.

**post-list.html**

```
<template name="postList">
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        {{ >postForm }}
        <h2>Posts for {{name}}</h2>
        <ul class="button-group myfilter">
            {{ #each posts }}
              {{ >postTypes }}
            {{ /each }}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**post-types.html**

```
<template name="postTypes">
    <li><a href="#" class="button tiny">{{postType}}</a></li>
</template>
```

Comment: I recommend doing step by step debugging with console.log.  First `console.log(this,$(this));console.log($(this).data('class'))` To ensure you are getting the right values

Comment: The issue is with 'this'. In your jquery function 'this' is bound to the selector. In Meteor event maps 'this' is bound to the template, or the template data, depending on the context in which the template is created. You will want to replace 'this' with something like event.target or template.find()

Comment: @JeremyS. That worked like a charm. If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `this`.

In your jquery function `this` is bound to the selector. In Meteor event maps `this` is bound to the template, or the template data, depending on the context in which the template is created.

You will want to replace `this` with something like `event.target` or `template.find()`.